# Why can't Smarty load this block tag plugin

Tags: php, smarty

Here is my directory structure:

./smartytest.php
./smarty31/* (libs, etc.)
./plugins/block.sayhi.php

The PHP code that initializes smarty is:

```
require_once('smarty31/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = getcwd() . '/templates';
$smarty->compile_dir  = getcwd() . '/templates_c';
$smarty->plugins_dir[] = getcwd() . '/plugins';
```

The PHP code for the plugin is:

```
<?php
    function smarty_block_sayhi($params, $content, $smarty, $open) {
        if (!$open) {
            return 'Hello: ' . $content;
        }
    }
?>
```

The error message I get is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message
>   'Syntax Error in template "/mypath/phptests/templates/page.tpl" on
>   line 11 "{sayhi}" unknown tag "sayhi"'

When the plugin was under the smarty31/libs/plugins directory, it loaded fine. Does this sample code not initialize Smarty correctly?

Comment: What is in the contents of "/mypath/phptests/templates/page.tpl" ? Looks like you have an unrecognised tag in there

Comment: Wow Smarty. That's a blast from the past. People still use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$smarty->plugins_dir[] = getcwd() . '/plugins';
```

Should be:

```
$existing = $smarty->getPluginsDir();
$existing[] = getcwd() . '/plugins';
$smarty->setPluginsDir($existing);
```

Turns out I was looking at a PHP 4 example; Smarty 3.1 uses PHP 5 access modifiers so I couldn't change plugins_dir that way.